# How can I use Shapely to detect all points that are closer than N meters?

Tags: python, numpy, shapely

Say I've got a list of points (the coordinates are in meters):

```
points = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (-1, 3), ..., (1000, 1000)]
```

And I want to use Shapely library to return all the points (from `points`) that are within `N` meters radius to some specified origin e.g., `(3, 3)`.

Update: if I execute:

```
import numpy as np
points = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 4), (100, 100), (5, 5), (1, 2)]
points_array = np.array(points)
print(points_array.shape)  # prints [n,2] where n is the number of points
max_distance = 2
origin = np.array([3, 3])
distance_array = np.sqrt((points_array - origin) ** 2)
near_points = points_array[distance_array < max_distance]
print('near points', near_points)
```

I receive

```
(6, 2)
near points [2 2 3 4 2]
```

which looks a bit weird because I didn't expect odd number of elements even though if I get `[(2, 2), (3, 4), 2=?]`

Comment: Do you need to use shapely? A simple and very fast solution would use numpy only without the need to create shapely objects (which is costly).

Comment: @oekopez well, I'd be happy with numpy as well if it's more efficient then.

Comment: Please see the update for my answer, I did a bug there. near_points is [[2,2],[3,4]] now.

Answer (score 4):

Fast calculations for lots of data are best handled with numpy. Instead of creating shapely objects from the coordinates and use the built in distance function, it is much easier (for points!, not for polygons) to calculate the distance using a numpy array. If you want to do the same for lines and polygons and use the nearest distances, shapely is your friend.

```
import numpy as np
points_array = np.array(points)
print(points_array.shape)  # prints [n,2] where n is the number of points
max_distance = 100
origin = np.array([3, 3])
```

Now calculate the euclidean distances as the square sum of the differences
over axis 1 (the coordinates)

```
distance_array = np.sqrt(np.sum((points_array - origin) ** 2, 1))
```

And retrieve the points where the distance is smaller than `max_distance`

```
near_points = points_array[distance_array < max_distance]
```

To compare the numpy solutions to the other answers in terms of speed I timed the answers for the same set of 1e6 random points:

- The code above takes 49 ms
- the optimized solution by Peter Collingridge: 44ms
- List solution by vurmax (using list comprehension, see below): 2.88s (60x slower)
- The list solution with Peter Collingridge's optimization: 2.48s
- Toy shapely solution by Christian Sloper: 15.2s (300x slower)

```
points_vurmax = [(x,y) for x,y in points_array 
                 if math.sqrt((x - origin[0])**2 + (y - origin[1])**2) < max_dist]
points_vurmax2 = [(x,y) for x,y in points_array 
                  if (x - origin[0])**2 + (y - origin[1])**2 < max_dist ** 2]
```

Comment: If you want to make this faster remove the `sqrt` operation and test against `max_distance` squared.

Comment: 42.8 vs 34 ms for 10e6 points. I prefer the more explicit variant

Answer (score 2):

Not going to be as fast as the numpy solutions, but here is one in shapely.

```
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint

m = MultiPoint(points)
circle = Point(3,3).buffer(N)
[p for p in m if circle.covers(p) ]
```

returns the points as shapely points.

Comment: I justed timed it to compare it with the numpy solution: 15.2s for 1e6 points, roughly 300 times slower.

Comment: I have no doubt that is true.

Comment: This is a toy solution.

Comment: Of course, and this is a toy benchmark. I thought it might be interesting to see how much slower it is for future readers. +1 for the shapely solution th OP asked for

Comment: Thanks for measuring, interesting to see how much faster numpy is.  A lesson to pick the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `shapely`. The distance function is just:

`d = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)`

You don't even need `numpy` or any another library except std `math`

```
from math import sqrt

points = [(1, 1), (2, 2), (-1, 3)]
target = (3, 4)
distance = 3
for x, y in points:
    if math.sqrt((x - target[0])**2 + (y - target[1])**2) < distance:
        print(x, y)
```

(Of course you can use `numpy`, if you have the huge amount of points and need to process them really fast)

Comment: I'd rather use `numpy` then since there're a lot of points (>= 10^6).

Comment: You don't even need `math`. Remove the `sqrt` operation and check against distance squared. It will be faster too.